# Imacro Twitter Following and Unfollowing

Tags: twitter, imacros, twitter-follow

I have a script like this

```
VERSION BUILD=8810214

SET !DATASOURCE test_one.csv  
SET !DATASOURCE_COLUMNS 2  
SET !LOOP 1  
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{!LOOP}}  
SET !EXTRACT_TEST_POPUP NO  
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES  
SET !ERRORCONTINUE YES  
SET !REPLAYSPEED FAST  
TAB T=1  
URL GOTO=https://twitter.com/{{!COL2}}  
WAIT SECONDS=3  
TAG POS=1 TYPE=BUTTON  ATTR=TXT:Follow`<SP>`Following`<SP>`Unfollow`<SP>`Blocked`<SP>`Unblock`<SP>`Pen*
```

When it loads a profile it follows it if it is not currently being followed but if it is being followed it clicks the following button and unfollows the user
how do it get it to just follow people who i am not already following but take no action on the users i am already following.
I am also confused as to how it is interpreting this line

```
ATTR=TXT:Follow`<SP>`Following`<SP>`Unfollow`<SP>`Blocked`<SP>`Unblock`<SP>`Pen*
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Twitter Follow button is like that. Has the same property for all states of the Following button. So if you run on someone you Follow you will Unfollow them. If you are not following them you will follow them.

That way they can detect bots.

The way to solve this is image recognition and that is in payed version of iMacros. Also you can solve this by using some other software like C# , PHP, Python .

Answer (score 1):

```
VERSION BUILD=7601105 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
TAG POS={{!LOOP}}  TYPE=BUTTON  ATTR=TXT:Follow<SP>Following<SP>Unfollow<SP>Blocked<SP>Unblock<SP>Pen*
```

Comment: When providing answers, it is beneficial to provide some comments to support why your answer is correct, rather than just providing some code.  Cheers.